# What machine learning algorithm to use for face matching?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, tensorflow

I want your opinion on what would be the best machine learning algorithm, or even better, library, to use if I wanted to match two faces that look similar. Kind of like how google photos can put photos of the same people in their own album automatically. What's the best way to tackle this?

Comment: This is a hot research-topic and answering about the best always have to consider the use-case. As this question is formulated, it shows some lack of research! If you are lazy and want to limit this research, read [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832), for which multiple implementations exist [(e.g. (openface)](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/).

Answer (score 1):

Face-based user identification isn't only one algorithm, it's a whole process that's still in active research. One way to experiment with it, is to follow these four steps:

1. Face region detection/extraction using the *Histogram of Oriented Gradients* (HOG)
2. Centralize eyes and lips using *face landmark estimation*
3. Image encoding using a CNN Model (openface for instance)
4. Image Search using a voisinage algorithm (KNN, LSHForest, etc)

Here's a blog article that draws a nice walk through the steps required to do face-based user identification:

- [machine learning is fun part 4 modern face recognition with deep learning](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78)